# Change network profile

Tags: networking

I have multiple network profiles, (one for DHCP another for fixed ip for my work, another fixed ip profile for config specific hardware.. etc etc..

Any Way to change wired network profiles like WIFI network connections like any linux distro? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

The buttons mentioned by [linux_tim](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/14774/13725) just provide configurations option of the network, not change to which network you want to connect to.

You can use `nmtui`, which is a text-based GUI to choose/configure network profiles.
Type `nmtui-connect` in the terminal. Then you can choose which network profile you want to activate/deactivate.

Comment: You are very correct! Thanks for adding the additional answer, Aiman!

Answer (score 0):

If you open System Setting and then Network, you can click on Ethernet. That will bring up the information for the wired connection and directly below the information are two buttons, Edit Connections and Advanced Settings.

If I understand the question correctly, you should find what you're looking for within those two areas.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way of manually selecting the profile from the gui (the first one is always selected), or to rearrange the profiles or set a default one.

One can select priorities for automatic activation, but it seems to be ignored.